# Showing the last error first instead of first(php)

Tags: php

I have a login form currently setup that confuses my users.
The way i handle errors is like this;

```
if (!($result->total > 0)) {
$err[] = "License key is not in our system.";
}
if ($claimed == 1) {
err[] = 'License key has been claimed already.';
}
if ($userID > 0) {
$err[] = 'License key is already connected to a user.';
}
if ($banned == 1) {
$err[] = 'License key is banned';
}
```

so for example, if one of my users would input a invalid license key instead of showing that it is not in our system it would show banned(creating confusion). Because i'm not exiting the code and letting it run.
I'm wondering how to go on about error handling when my functions are set up like this.
update -
Forgot to show how i'm displaying the error.. my fault!

```
if (empty($err)) {
//no errors
} else {
echo $err; //this will show the last error instead of the first error generated
}
```

Comment: Is your objective here to only show them the first message then?

Comment: `...if ($banned == 1) {` ?

Answer (score 1):

OK Bob,

It would be helpful if you were showing us how you are presenting your errors, as what you are explaining would suggest that your `$err` array would then contain two values, not just (the last) one.

However, what I think is going on here is that your `$banned` condition will always be met; unless you add another `=` to your `if` statement, like this:

```
if (!($result->total > 0)) {
    $err[] = "License key is not in our system.";
}
if ($claimed == 1) {
    err[] = 'License key has been claimed already.';
}
if ($userID > 0) {
    $err[] = 'License key is already connected to a user.';
}
if ($banned == 1) { # <-- Here
    $err[] = 'License key is banned';
}
```

Then for testing purposes you can view the array of errors:

```
if(isset($err) && !empty($err)){
    print_r($err);
}
```

If you want to loop through each potential error:

```
if(isset($err) && !empty($err)){
   foreach($err as $error){
      echo "Error because: {$error}".PHP_EOL;
   }
}
```

Comment: I forgot to show how i'm displaying the errors(basically i'm checking if it's empty) 
I updated it, btw the banned was a type

Comment: @BobVerd Check the updated answer; because `$err` is an array, you should `print_r` or loop through possible errors.

Answer (score 0):

So you are adding all the errors to the array `err`.

To display the first item in an array, just use `[0]`  to access the first index.

```php
if (empty($err)) {
  //no errors
} else {
  echo $arr[0];
}
```